# Python regex substitute group 1 to certain string

Tags: python, regex

I wonder how to substitute group 1 with certain string by regex in python.

**Question1:**

```
str = "aaa bbb ccc"
regex = "\baaa (bbb)\b"
repl = "111 bbb 222"
```

Use regex to match str, matched "aaa bbb", and replace group1 "bbb" with "111 bbb 222", and get the result "aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc"

```
str_repl = "aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc"
```

Thanks for @RomanPerekhrest and @janos 's lookbehind method.

And I wonder how to solve a more general scenario:

**Question2:**

```
s1 = "bBb"
regex = "(?<=\baaa )" + s1 + "\b"  # may not suitable
repl = "XxX " + s1 + " YyY"
```

target:

```
s0 = "aaa bBb ccc"
s0_repl = "aaa XxX bBb YyY ccc"

s1 = "aaa bbb ccc"
no match

s2 = "AAA bBb ccc"
s2_repl = "AAA XxX bBb YyY ccc"
```

Ignore the case for substring except of s1 when matching in original string.

**Question3:**

```
s1 = "bbb"
regex = "(?<=\baaa )" + s1 + "\b"  # may not suitable
repl = "XxX " + s1 + " YyY"
```

target:

```
s0 = "aaa bBb ccc"
s0_repl = "aaa XxX bBb YyY ccc"

s1 = "aaa bbb ccc"
s1_repl = "aaa XxX bbb YyY ccc"

s2 = "AAA BBB ccc"
s2_repl = "AAA XxX BBB YyY ccc"
```

Ignore the case for substring except of s1 when matching & substituting in original string.

**Question4:**

If there is a way to substitute group 1 on original string by regex on python?

Comment: your *general scenario* sounds simple and complex simultaneously. Can you elaborate to make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry for deleted some descriptions just now. Please check the question's details again.

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/yTUgsS).

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for your demo, I added question 2-4 above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` package, and positive look-behind:

```
import re
s = "aaa bbb ccc"
regex = r"\b(?<=aaa )(bbb)\b"
repl = "111 bbb 222"
print(re.sub(regex, repl, s))
```

This will produce:

```
aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc
```

Notice the changes I did there:

- The `aaa` prefix in the regex is wrapped in `(?<=...)`. This means, match `bbb` if it follows `aaa`, without including `aaa` in the pattern to replace. This is called [positive lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Without this change to your regex, the `aaa` would disappear together with `bbb`
- Regular expression strings should be written as `r"..."`, to make them raw strings, in order to avoid problems with escape sequences
- I renamed the `str` variable to `s`, because `str` is a reserved word in Python, as @elena also pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

To replace sequence `bbb` which should be preceded by sequence `aaa` use the following approach:

```
s = "aaa bbb ccc"
regex = r"(?<=aaa )bbb\b"
repl = "111 bbb 222"

str_replaced = re.sub(regex, repl, s)
print(str_replaced)
```

The output:

```
aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc
```

---

`(?<=aaa )` - lookbehind positive assertion, ensures that `"bbb"` is preceded by `"aaa "`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you! So could I replace group1 by python's regex or I could just use this way?

Comment: in your simple case you don't even need to enclose `bbb` into capturing group, just use lookbehind and word boundary as shown above. I will match sequence `bbb` as a separate word which is preceded by `"aaa "`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `str` as a variable name. It's a reserved keyword in Python.

```
import re

str1 = "aaa bbb ccc"
re.sub("bbb", "111 bbb 222", str1)
Out[11]: 'aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc'
```

Comment: I just want to match the "bbb" start with "aaa ", so this answer may not be suitable.